# WebServiceTemplate timeout works only when it is configured under 21 seconds

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

i'm trying to set a timeout on a webservicetemplate and it works only if it is under 21 seconds, if i try to set the timeout over 21 seconds it won't work it will timeout everytime when it reaches 21 seconds.I've tried lots of configs and mostly all of them are doing the same thing.

```
@Bean
public WebServiceTemplate munisService() {
    WebServiceTemplate template = new WebServiceTemplate();

    template.setMarshaller(service1Marshaller());
    template.setUnmarshaller(service1Marshaller());

    template.setDefaultUri(ancomUrl);

    HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender();
    httpComponentsMessageSender.setReadTimeout(180000);
    httpComponentsMessageSender.setConnectionTimeout(180000);
    template.setMessageSender(httpComponentsMessageSender);

    return template;
}

@Bean
ServiceImpl ServiceBean(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    ServiceImpl service= new ServiceImpl ();
    service.setWebServiceTemplate(munisService());
    service.setDefaultUri(ancomUrl);
    service.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    service.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    return service;
}
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?
If it helps this is the exception and i'm using httpclient 4.5.13

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Also the request is done on localhost, i'm running a spring boot app on localhost which does some requests.

Comment: My guess is that there is a second timeout that is taking effect.  If two timeouts exist on the same operation, it makes sense that the shorter one would win, which is why you see a difference in behavior if you set the one timeout to a small value, but not otherwise.

Comment: i guess you are right but i have just a simple spring boot app which calls a wsdl

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this configuration property in `application.yaml` if you use an embedded server with spring boot

```
server.connection-timeout=120s
```

It can be that the server itself forces a timeout to the connection after those 21 seconds

Can you try in your code with

```
httpComponentsMessageSender.setReadTimeout(0);
httpComponentsMessageSender.setConnectionTimeout(0);
```

According to documentation `0` value means never timeout. Then we maybe retrieve something more from logs as to what causes that timout.

[spring documentation for httpComponentsMessageSender](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/transport/http/HttpComponentsMessageSender.html)

Comment: i've tried with both of those
server:
  connection-timeout: 120s
  tomcat:
    connection-timeout: 120s
and it still does the same

Comment: i did that and it still gives me timeout when reaches 21 seconds :( so it looks like there is somehow another timeout defined but i don't know where. i've seen that the httpComponentsMessageSender has a httpClient maybe this httpClient has some sort of timeout?