# HttpClient connection timeout after 10 seconds

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x

I implemented a custom CloseableHttpClient like below:

```
        private WebServiceMessageSender createWebServiceMessageSender() {
            HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender();

            RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setSocketTimeout(30_000)
                    .setConnectTimeout(30_000)
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(30_000)
                    .build();

            SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom()
                    .setSoTimeout(4000)
                    .build();

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .addInterceptorFirst(new HttpComponentsMessageSender.RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor())
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                    .setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
                    .disableAutomaticRetries()
                    .build();

            httpComponentsMessageSender.setHttpClient(httpClient);
            return httpComponentsMessageSender;
        }
```

and I injected this method to WebServiceTemplate as setMessageSender.

The problem is receiving the connection timeout (not the read timeout!) after 10 seconds, not as I configured above (4000 milliseconds). I have no idea why this webservice does not execute the timeout at the specified time, but waits 10 seconds. Has anyone had a similar problem?

Dependencies:

- Spring-Boot: 2.7.x
- spring-ws-core: 3.1.3
- httpclient: 4.5.13

I`m calling google.com on port 81

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java HTTP Client Request with defined timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000214/java-http-client-request-with-defined-timeout)

Comment: @aled I received `message=I/O error: null; nested exception is org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException` in under 1sec ms when I implemented the code from the accepted answer. Also this method is deprecated in HttpClient 4.5.x

Comment: setting `httpComponentsMessageSender.setReadTimeout(30000)` and `httpComponentsMessageSender.setConnectionTimeout(4000)` also doesn't help

Comment: almost identical problem is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478510/webservicetemplate-timeout-works-only-when-it-is-configured-under-21-seconds?rq=2

Comment: the problem is in Istio mesh config `connectTimeout` https://cloudnative.to/istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.mesh.v1alpha1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10s connection timeout is default value in Istio MeshConfig connectTimeout https://istio.io/v1.12/docs/reference/config/istio.mesh.v1alpha1/